# Keep Heading Text in Same Position in Relation to Background Container

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have an h1 heading inside a parent container, and I would like it so whatever the screen width, the h1 text is always in the same position in relation to the parent container (i.e. the one with grey background).

When I reduce the window size the grey parent container moves out of alignment, as if it is being pulled the left at a faster rate than the text moves to the left?

I'm pretty sure this is possible but it is driving me a bit mad trying to find a way of doing it.

Also **I MUST** use the width calculation given on the parent container for reasons there's no point going into.

Any help would be awesome.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/NZoMbQ

or

Code snippet below.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3.583rem 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh;
}

.left-background-box {
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  width: calc(10% + (27.133% - 1rem));
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 3rem;
  position: relative;
  left: 65%;
  margin: 1.728rem 0;
  line-height: 4.299rem;
  width: 30rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
    <div class="left-background-box">
        <h1 class="heading">This is a good two<br>
          Line Title to use
      </h1>
        <h3 class="subheading">Focused on the Issues That Affect You.</h3>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the `.left-background-box` width changes in a different rate than the position of the `.heading` is that one has a width calculation based on percentages and static values, and the other has it's `left` attribute value based only on percentage.

If you have to use the specific `calc` for the width of the `.left-background-box`, you should use it at the `left` of the `.heading` as well. You can also simplify it to `calc(37.133% - 1rem)`.

The only difference is that you need to make some more calculation to adjust the same rate, because the `.heading` is nested inside the `.left-background-box` and percentage will consider its parent width. But if you have a full width section as the parent of both, you can use the same values by using `vw` instead of `%`. You can also adjust the "static" value (here is the `-1rem` to adjust the alignment of the heading)

Here is an example: [codepen](https://codepen.io/dordasal/pen/jjdppJ)

Comment: Do you know if it possible to award a bounty directly to an answer? Still owe you 50 points. :)